# groupBy and orderBy Laravel for getting higher value

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have problem when grouping and ordering the result of my query.
here is my data

```
+--------+-----------+----------+--------+-------+
| id_krs | id_mhs_pt | id_kelas | status | nilai |
+--------+-----------+----------+--------+-------+
|     38 | 3         |  29      | B      | A     |
|     45 | 3         |  30      | B      | A     |
|     46 | 3         |  31      | B      | C     |
|  18393 | 3         |  31      | U      | A     |
+--------+-----------+----------+--------+-------+
```

here is my query

```
DB::table('krs')->select('id_krs','id_mhs_pt','id_kelas','status','nilai')
    ->where('id_mhs_pt',3)->groupBy('id_kelas')->orderBy('nilai','asc')->get();
```

when i run the query, the result is:

```
+--------+-----------+----------+--------+-------+
| id_krs | id_mhs_pt | id_kelas | status | nilai |
+--------+-----------+----------+--------+-------+
|     38 | 3         |  29      | B      | A     |
|     45 | 3         |  30      | B      | A     |
|     46 | 3         |  31      | B      | C     |
+--------+-----------+----------+--------+-------+
```

and the result i want is

```
+--------+-----------+----------+--------+-------+
| id_krs | id_mhs_pt | id_kelas | status | nilai |
+--------+-----------+----------+--------+-------+
|     38 | 3         |  29      | B      | A     |
|     45 | 3         |  30      | B      | A     |
|  18393 | 3         |  31      | U      | A     |
+--------+-----------+----------+--------+-------+
```

Because the id_krs 18393 have greater nilai (score) than id_krs 46 (both using same id_kelas). I tried to change the order to asc or desc, but the result still the same. How to get that? Thank's!

Comment: What `Laravel`version?

Comment: @ConstantinGALBENU Laravel 5.2

Comment: Please see my answer and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you loose the `order` on `group by`, so you must use a temporary table to get the minimum `nilai` for each `id_kelas` then join it in order to fetch the other columns:

```
DB::table('krs')
    ->select('id_krs', 'id_mhs_pt', 'id_kelas', 'status', 'nilai')
    ->leftJoin(
        DB::raw('(select id_krs, min(nilai) as m_nilai FROM krs GROUP BY id_kelas) tmp'), function ($join) {
            $join
                ->on(DB::raw('tmp.id_krs'), '=', DB::raw('krs.id_krs'))
                ->on(DB::raw('tmp.m_nilai'), '=', DB::raw('krs.nilai'));
        }
    )
    ->where('id_mhs_pt', 3)
    ->orderBy('nilai', 'asc')
    ->get();
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, but it still return the value almost the same as my data (4 rows), the difference is in the order, the order in the result by id_krs is 38, 45, 18393, 46.

Comment: anyway i solved my problem by creating 1 more table to store the nilai's value, thank you for your help!